# Transform 2 RxJava Observables to 1 Map

Tags: java, dictionary, stream, rx-java

I have following scenario. I'm getting data from server using Retrofit2. 
I want to download `Collection<Account>` of `Account` entities, and for each of those accounts to download `Collection<Project>` of `Project` entities. At the end I want to get `Map<Account, Collection<Project>> accountsWithProjects`.

I have following methods:

1. `Observable<Collection<Account>> requestAllAccounts()`
2. `Observable<Collection<Project>> requestProjectsInfoForTempoAccount(Account accunt)`

**Question:** Is it possible to zip or create somehow foreach iteration of these two reactive streams and collect all the items to the map?

I can also get the collection of projects for account synchronously if it helps, however can't do it on main thread, since developing for Android and the result must be observed on main thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a better way:

```
requestAllAccounts()
.flatMap(account -> requestProjectsInfoForTempoAccount(account),
   (acccount, projects) -> Pair::of)
.toMap(Pair::key, Pair::value);
```

(expansion to Java 7 left as an excercise for the reader)

Answer (score 1):

There you have it:

```
requestAllAccounts().flatMap(new Func1<Collection<Account>, Observable<Account>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<Account> call(Collection<Account> accountCollection) {
            return Observable.from(accountCollection);
        }
    }).flatMap(new Func1<Account, Observable<Pair<Account, Collection<Project>>>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<Pair<Account, Collection<Project>>> call(Account account) {
            return Observable.just(account).zipWith(requestProjectsInfoForTempoAccount(account),
                    new Func2<Account, Collection<Project>, Pair<Account, Collection<Project>>>() {
                        @Override
                        public Pair<Account, Collection<Project>> call(Account account, Collection<Project> projects) {
                            return new Pair<Account, Collection<Project>>(account, projects);
                        }
                    });
        }
    }).toList()
            .flatMap(new Func1<List<Pair<Account, Collection<Project>>>, Observable<Map<Account, Collection<Project>>>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<Map<Account, Collection<Project>>> call(List<Pair<Account, Collection<Project>>> pairs) {
                    Map<Account, Collection<Project>> map = new HashMap<Account, Collection<Project>>();
                    for (Pair<Account, Collection<Project>> pair : pairs) {
                        map.put(pair.first, pair.second);
                    }
                    return Observable.just(map);
                }
            });
```

What is going on here?

1. Get all accounts.
2. Split list into single accounts
3. Invoke searching for projects on single account and return the `Pair<Account, Collection<Project>>`
4. Merge all objects
5. Transform `List<Pair<Account, Collection<Project>>>` to `Map<Account, Collection<Project>>`

Comment: Thanks, there is only one issue I'm trying to resolve: The observable you created is emitting many `Map<Account, Collection<Project>>` instances. Each instance with only one Map.Entry. Is there a way to merge them all in one Map before subscribing?

Comment: Are you sure? If the functions `requestAllAccounts()` and `requestProjectsInfoForTempoAccount(Account accunt)` return the collections only once (one `onNext(...)` call) it should work as expected.

Comment: Yes, sorry u're right. I tried to rewrite it with lambdas and messed something. Thanks again!